How to expand a MudBlazor table with only 1 row?
When I show the MudBlazor table, it initially looks like this:

In the code, I'm preloading an empty row, so when I click in the bottom area below the line under "Outcome", it expands and looks like this:

How do I programmatically get the table into the state of the second image - showing the blank row?
I've tried using SetSelectedItem with a StateHasChanged(), but that didn't seem to expand that row. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's what I did to get it to work:
 protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        theRow = tblDesiredOutcome.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Position == Id);
        if (theRow is not null) tblDesiredOutcome.SetSelectedItem(theRow);
        tblDesiredOutcome.SetEditingItem(theRow);
        //SelectedRowClassFunc(item, 1);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);

